# While loop problem about square numbers 's task

Tags: python, python-3.x

The task is to write a function `square(n:int) -> List[int]` that returns all the positive square numbers less than n in increasing order.

and my code is

```
def square(n: int) -> list[int]:
    counter = 1
    output_list = []
    while counter * counter < n:
        output_list.append(counter * counter)
    counter += 1
    return output_list
```

Comment: By the way, there's a bug in the posted code.  The statement `counter += 1` is outside of the loop.  Move it inside the loop by indenting it 4 more spaces.

Comment: @TomKarzes thanks, after I added the indentation and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
Python 3.8.10
```

code :

```
def square(n: int) -> list:
    counter = 1
    output_list = []
    while counter * counter < n:
        output_list.append(counter * counter)
        counter += 1
    return output_list
    
print('square 88 : ', square(88))
```

output:

```
square 88 :  [1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

about return type:

`def square(n: int) -> 'list[int]' :`  works (Forward references When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

`def square(n: int) -> list :` works

`def square(n: int) -> list[int] :`   error !!! TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

or use:

```
from typing import List

def square(n: int) -> List[int] :
```

works

The `list` type didn't become generic until Python 3.9;